# appendChild work only when it's inside settimeout

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm creating a drag and drop application using this method

```js
indexbut=-1;
addComponent(componentClass: ComponentFactory<any>, target) {
    let componentRef: ComponentRef<any> = this.container.createComponent(componentClass);
if (componentClass.selector == 'app-button') {
      this.currentComponent = componentRef.instance;
      this.currentComponent.selfRef = this.currentComponent;
      this.currentComponent.index = 'button' + ++this.indexbut;
    setTimeout(() => {
        target.appendChild(window.document.getElementById(componentRef.instance.index))
    }, 0);
}
```

my problem is that the appendChild don't work properly if it's in settiemout , is there any idea to keep this method synchrounous (deleting the settiemout ) .

Comment: createComponent is async? - does it have a callback function?

Comment: it's synchrounous I think

Comment: How do you calculate `index`?

Comment: it's a complicated methode that's why 'm putting juste those few lines , i'll edit the code to make it more clear

Comment: You should use nativeElement of the component instance to manipulate it..

Comment: it works by now but i want to delete the settimeout

Comment: Probably because when you your settimeout like this. you defer the execution of that callback until after the current execution context has been cleared. So it looks like your addComponent function must be fully completed before you can interact with it on DOM lvl.

Comment: clearly, currentComponent isn't in the DOM yet, which is why you need to use setTimeout

Comment: Yes that's what happen but it makes me a lot of problems when saving the components and targets into the database and trying to reproduce the compnents saved state with this method